# Why are HotSpots compilation log times different to ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()?

Tags: java, jvm, benchmarking, jvm-hotspot

When I start the JVM with the argument

```
-XX:+PrintCompilation
```

the output is like this:

```
 60    1             java.lang.String::hashCode (55 bytes)
 74    2             sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder::encode (361 bytes)
```

The first column is the time stamp in millisecond, when the log was printed, and I want to compare this time stamp to the value that gets returned by `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()`:

```
long jvmUpTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();
```

or

```
long jvmStartTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();
```

But my result is like this:

```
[62:log from Java code]
103    5             benchmark.AbstractBenchmarkST::benchmark (82 bytes)
[62:log from Java code]
```

It seems that there is about 40 ms difference between them, which makes the two time stamps incomparable. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Which code is writing `[62:log...` two times?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

The time printed in the first column of HotSpots JIT compilation logs (when starting the JVM with the "-XX:+PrintCompilation" argument), is of a constant duration greater than the time returned by ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime() (given that getUptime is invoked at about the same time as a compilation log gets printed).

This is at least true for JDK 7 running under Windows 7 and can be easily verified by executing the following code with "-XX:+PrintCompilation":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("JVM uptime: " + ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime());
}
```

The result should look something like this:

> ```
>  77    1             java.lang.String::hashCode (55 bytes)
>  79    2             java.lang.String::indexOf (70 bytes)
>  80    3             java.lang.String::charAt (29 bytes)
>  82    4             java.lang.String::lastIndexOf (52 bytes)
>  82    5             java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
>  82    6             java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::ensureCapacityInternal (16 bytes)
>  82    7             java.lang.String::indexOf (166 bytes)
>  85    8     n       java.lang.System::arraycopy (native)   (static)
> ```
>
> JVM uptime: 43

Even though ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime() was called after the printed JIT compilations, the time returned seems to point to an earlier invocation.

> It seems that they have a around 40 ms difference, this difference makes it incomparable. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Since the time difference is constant and shouldn't change throughout running a JVM, one should still be able to compare the times, as long as one takes the time difference into account.

**Long Answer**

The "-XX:+PrintCompilation" JVM argument is hardly documented and one can only guess, that the first column represents a time stamp relative to the startup of the JVM. If one has a look at the source code of the HotSpot compiler, it becomes clear though, that the times printed by PrintCompilation and the times returned by ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime() reference two entirely different time stamps that get both initialized during the startup of the JVM.

The compilation logs get printed during calls to [CompileTask::print_compilation_impl](https://bitbucket.org/jaroslav/hotspot/src/0f80645e9c266c2bddad6fd94423b7ae20534b09/src/share/vm/compiler/compileBroker.cpp?at=default#cl-382):

```
void CompileTask::print_compilation_impl(outputStream* st, Method* method, int compile_id, int comp_level,
                                        bool is_osr_method, int osr_bci, bool is_blocking,
                                        const char* msg, bool short_form) {
    if (!short_form) {
        st->print("%7d ", (int) st->time_stamp().milliseconds());  // print timestamp
    }
    st->print("%4d ", compile_id);    // print compilation number
    [...]
}
```

st->time_stamp() is implemented in ostream.cpp and refers to a [TimeStamp](https://bitbucket.org/jaroslav/hotspot/src/0f80645e9c266c2bddad6fd94423b7ae20534b09/src/share/vm/runtime/timer.cpp) that gets initialized with the time returned by os::elapsed_counter():

[ostream.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/jaroslav/hotspot/src/0f80645e9c266c2bddad6fd94423b7ae20534b09/src/share/vm/utilities/ostream.cpp?at=default#cl-197):

```
 void outputStream::stamp() {
     if (! _stamp.is_updated()) {
         _stamp.update(); // start at 0 on first call to stamp()
     }
     [...]
 }
```

[timer.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/jaroslav/hotspot/src/0f80645e9c266c2bddad6fd94423b7ae20534b09/src/share/vm/runtime/timer.cpp#cl-86):

```
 void TimeStamp::update() {
     update_to(os::elapsed_counter());
 }
```

os::elapsed_counter() gets in turn initialized by a call to os::init() during the [startup of the JVM](https://bitbucket.org/jaroslav/hotspot/src/0f80645e9c266c2bddad6fd94423b7ae20534b09/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp?at=default#cl-3284):

```
jint Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs* args, bool* canTryAgain) {
    [...]
    os::init();
    [...]
}
```

The java method ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime() on the other hand refers to a native method in [VMManagementImpl.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/management/VMManagementImpl.java#178):

```
public native long getStartupTime();
```

which is implemented in [VMManagementImpl.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/native/sun/management/VMManagementImpl.c#L192) and returns the time from the JmmInterface constant JMM_JVM_INIT_DONE_TIME_MS:

[management.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/jaroslav/hotspot/src/0f80645e9c266c2bddad6fd94423b7ae20534b09/src/share/vm/services/management.cpp?at=default#cl-1010):

```
  case JMM_JVM_INIT_DONE_TIME_MS:
       return Management::vm_init_done_time();
```

which gets initialized during the start up of the JVM quite some time after os::init() was already called:

```
jint Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs* args, bool* canTryAgain) {
    [...]
    os::init();
    [...]
    // record VM initialization completion time
    Management::record_vm_init_completed();
    [...]
}
```

Therefore the time printed by JIT compilation logs is different than the time returned by ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime().